# Radius of convergence of power series given other power series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $R\in(0, \infty)$ be the radius of convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,$$ where $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is any sequence of positive numbers. Now consider the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{-1}_nx^n.$$ Will its radius of convergence always be $1/R$ or can it assume other values?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Hadamard formula?

Answer (score 1):

For the first series we have radius of convergence $$R_1=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|a_n|^{1/n}},$$ by the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem. For the second series we have $$R_2=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|a_n|^{-1/n}}.$$ Is it true that $R_1=1/R_2$?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Can there be a sequence $a_n$ such that $R_1\neq 1/R_2$?